# admob, The interstitial wasn't loaded yet

Tags: java, android, admob

someone knows why in my android app when I run it in the emulator the admob advertising works and when I run it on my cell phone nothing comes out.

my code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-4118735753673684~3449528029");
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4118735753673684/1445658390");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
    }
```

Comment: when I run it in the android studio emulator at the top I get a title that says test, I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: can you capture logs from your phone and update in your question? It will tell you why it is failing